# Using custom user model after having run migrate for the first time

Tags: django

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) it says that if I want to override the default user model in a project, I need to do so before running any migrations or running `manage.py migrate` for the first time. **I wonder what happens if I do the opposite, which is changing the user model to a custom one AFTER having run the migrations.** I only have myself registered as a user to test the functionality of my web app, if I lose it, it doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind losing data, then there is no problem. You should drop your existing database and delete all the migrations that have been created - this is one of the few times when deleting migrations is appropriate.

Now, you can change your user class and run makemigrations again; from Django's point of view, this is now the first time.